# Automatically send Skype chat notifications to email?

Tags: email, skype

I don't like to run skype all the time anymore. Is there any way to get chat notifications sent to my email account?

Answer (score 12):

You may run Skype "headless" on any Linux server or workstation you have access to and have Skype send each incoming text message via email.

The headless setup is attained using Xvfb X virtual framebuffer. This way your instance of Skype will run completely in background, perhaps on a remote machine, without actually showing anything on any graphics display.

Re-sending Skype messages via email is done with the Linux Skype's "Execute script on Notifications" feature.

This feature runs any command of your choice with two possible parameters: sender name or Skype id and message text. A working example of such command line could be

```
echo "%smessage" | /usr/bin/mail -s "Skype message from %sname" your@email.com
```

You can also register another Skype account to run normally and forward voice calls to it for free from your main account running headless.

(There is also a way to forward Skype voice calls from the headless Skype to a SIP server for free, but that's another story altogether.)

Comment: Is this still possible in 2016, using the latest 2014 version of Skype for Linux? I have no clue how to run Skype headless.

Answer (score 1):

Not supported, nor do I think it will ever be.

Comment: I don't know about that, since Skype is moving from a P2P architecture to a cloud-based architecture.